# Error: failed to find element matching selector img

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm web scraping with puppeteer but when one element (image) is not found in one of the objects, I get an error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error: failed to find element matching selector ".css-13u5hxa.epu0oo22 img"`

How to continue running the application even if the error occurs? I know that some objects that will be scraped won't have image but still would like to get them.

Below is the const that causes the error

````
const companyImage = await page.$eval(
     // ".oc-photo-gallery .photo__10vsfGte img",
     ".css-13u5hxa.epu0oo22 img",
     (img) => img.src
   );
   


   listings[i].companyImage = companyImage;
   const listingModel = new GlassdoorDB(listings[i]);
   await listingModel.save();
   await sleep(1000); //1 second sleep```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in a try/catch, log the error and continue

````js
try {
    const companyImage = await page.$eval(
        // ".oc-photo-gallery .photo__10vsfGte img",
        ".css-13u5hxa.epu0oo22 img",
        (img) => img.src
    );



    listings[i].companyImage = companyImage;
    const listingModel = new GlassdoorDB(listings[i]);
    await listingModel.save();
    await sleep(1000); //1 second sleep```
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
}
````